# background color and border are not working

Tags: html, css, class, background-color

I'm trying to get a background color for `class="imgd"` but nothing shows up.

```css
.portrait {
  border: #C7C7C7 solid 1px;
}

.circular--square {
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding-right: 10%;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
}

.imgd {
  text-align: center;
  border: solid px G7G7G7;
  background-color: gggggg;
}
```

```html
<div class="lgcontainer">
  <h1>Aristotle Onassis</h1>
  <h2>1906 - 1975</h2>
  <h3>One of the richest people in the 20th century</h3>
  <div class="description">Aristotle Socrates Onassis (Aristotelis Onasis; 20th January 1906 - 15th March 1975), [1] commonly called Ari or Aristo Onassis, was a Greek-Argentine shipping magnate, who amassed the world's largest privately owned shipping fleet and was one of the world's richest and most famous men.</div>
  <div class="portrait">
    <img class="circular--square" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/46/Aristotle_Onassis.JPG" alt="Rich Boi">
    <span class="imgd">The most well-known portrait of Onassis.</span>
  </div>
  <br>
  <h4><strong>The following list is a timeline of Onassis Life</strong></h4>
</div>
```

Comment: gggggg and g7g7g7 is not a valid color. Try adding #aaa, red, yellow etc... https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors_legal.asp

Comment: Please do not post images of your code. They're considered low-quality and let you appear lazy. Use a code snippet (**Ctrl+M**) instead. Copy and paste your code into the snippet. Makes it easier for us to work and debug your code instead of needing to type it down from an image (because you where to lazy to use copy & paste).

Answer (score 2):

According to the pictures you are missing a number or pixels, also color format is incorrect, it looks similar to HEX but `#` is missing at the beginning and G is not a valid hex digit:

```
border: solid [number] px [#][AAAAAA]
```

Comment: Your right. However the statement `color should be HEX` is an unlucky phrasing -> `If the color should be hex, then G is not a hex-digit` colors dont have to be `HEX`. They can be used by using the `color-name`, `rgb`, `rgba`, `hsl`, `cmyk`...

Comment: @tacoshy You are right, thanks for the correction.

Comment: thank you for editing the "Unlucky phrase" - now I have no further objection to not upvote the anwser

Answer (score -1):

I saw your HTML file it is not linked with CSS

link your .CSS file in HTML, then you are go

you can include this and change the href as per your CSS file name
keep the below code after

Comment: Downvoted for technical incorrection. That is not the issue. The issue is caused by typos as there are no valid colors declared.